# Mechanize to log into oracle account

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm trying to create a ruby tool which logs me into my oracle account with mechanize and displays the following home site.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize' 
require 'nokogiri'

agent = Mechanize.new
login_form = agent.get("https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp").form("LoginForm")
login_form.request_id = 'username'
login_form.locale = 'password'

page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)
page.body.match /content="1;URL=(.*?)"/
nexturl = $1
newpage = agent.get nexturl
puts newpage.body
```

At the moment I'm able to load the next page but I only get a message that the login failed ("System error. Please re-try your action.").
Maybe the problem is that the login site is a https:// site?

I found out that the problem is that Mechanize doesn't even get the required login fields:

```
<form method="post" action="/oam/server/sso/auth_cred_submit" name="LoginForm"         autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" name="v" value="v1.4">
<input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="">
<span id="errormsg" class="error-show">
Error! Do not use bookmarked URL.<br>Please type the URL you are trying to reach directly into your browser.
</span>
</form>
```

If I curl the site I get these errors and the required fields aren't even in the received form.
The fields I need to login start where the Error Message is ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please remove `oracle` tag. This is not relevant to Oracle.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that request_id and locale are the right fields to enter username and password in.